# SCSS - Nested css classes result in different sizes (width & height)

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, sprite

Why does this make a difference in the size of my buttons.

This gives me very small buttons:

```
.btn {
  fill: $btn-icon-standard;

  &.--desk {
    width: 56px;
    height: 39px;
  }
}
```

as opposed to this, which gives me bigger ones:

```
.btn-desk {
  fill: $btn-icon-standard;
  width: 56px;
  height: 39px;
}
```

Why is this so? The scss is applied to a svg sprite by the way, if this should be of any help!

edit:
I am aware that in the first case I have to use `btn desk` as the class of my button, whereas in the latter case I do `btn-desk` as class of the element.

I am using the buttons in my html like so:

```
<svg class="btn --desk"> //in the latter case i use btn-desk of course
 <use xlink:href="#btn-desk" />
</svg>
```

My corresponding sprite:

```
  <symbol id="btn-desk" viewBox="0 0 56 39">
    <g id="homepage" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="chosen" transform="translate(-217.000000, -812.000000)">
            <g id="Group" transform="translate(217.000000, 812.000000)">
                <path d="M12.6983173,-10.7712321 C12.6983173,-11.5732117 13.3431282,-12.2233446 14.1459422,-12.2233446 L42.1229451,-12.2233446 C42.9224463,-12.2233446 43.5705701,-11.5825593 43.5705701,-10.7712321 L43.5705701,41.6777729 C43.5705701,42.4797525 42.9257592,43.1298854 42.1229451,43.1298854 L14.1459422,43.1298854 C13.3464411,43.1298854 12.6983173,42.4891002 12.6983173,41.6777729 L12.6983173,-10.7712321 Z M16.5573489,-6.82368293 C16.5573489,-7.62220908 17.2007906,-8.26954242 18.0057472,-8.26954242 L38.2631402,-8.26954242 C39.0630685,-8.26954242 39.7115385,-7.61689199 39.7115385,-6.82368293 L39.7115385,37.7302238 C39.7115385,38.5287499 39.0680968,39.1760833 38.2631402,39.1760833 L18.0057472,39.1760833 C17.2058189,39.1760833 16.5573489,38.5234328 16.5573489,37.7302238 L16.5573489,-6.82368293 Z" id="Combined-Shape" transform="translate(28.134444, 15.453270) rotate(-270.000000) translate(-28.134444, -15.453270) "></path>
                <rect id="Rectangle-17" x="4.67153159" y="34.9157933" width="46.3083791" height="3.95380214" rx="1.45152"></rect>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
  </symbol>
```

Comment: You know that you are selecting different elements in both cases, right?

Comment: well yes, in my html I have changed the classes from `btn desk` to `btn-desk` respectively, if this is what you mean. I should maybe mention this. Or did you mean sth else?

Comment: No, was just checking if that was not perhaps the root of the problem already. In that case, we will need more code to make the problem reproducible. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: thanks. I edited some things.

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: `--desk` is an invalid classname. Class names must begin with a letter [A-Za-z].

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax mistakes on your selector expression

```css
.btn {
  &.desk { color: green; }
}
/* output: */
.btn.desk { color: green; }


/* but you may need for */
.btn {
  &-desk { color: green; }
}
/* which output: */
.btn-desk { color: green; }
```

Comment: I dont understand. I am aware there is a different in output, and I am using different syntax to call the different css variations from my HTML in each case. Or what am i missing here?

Comment: He/she is saying you have an actual syntax issue.   &.--desk is not going to work, as .--desk is not a valid class first off, and you don't put a period with the ampersand to add to the parent class.  `.btn {  &--desk { } }` is more specifically what you're asking for, as opposed to `.btn {  &.--desk { } }`.  The former outputs `.btn--desk {}`, as the latter would output `.btn.--desk {}`